# access runtime and developer extensions - how does it affect current installation?

Tags: ms-access

i already have the full blown access installed

i am going to distribute my access front end and will need to install the 2007 runtime on people's computers.

1. what is the purpose of the access developer extensions?
2. can i install the runtime on my machine even though i already have the entire version installed?

Comment: There's this handy thing called Google and if you put in "what are the access developer extensions" there, the first link will answer the first of your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to install the runtime to test an app in runtime mode -- just start our app with the /runtime switch, or change it's extension to end in "r", e.g., ACCDR or MDR.

Answer (score 2):

You can't install the runtime on your computer if you already have that version of access installed (at least you can't with the supplied installer).

It is important to realize that all of the SAME problems that exist when installing the full version of access on a target computer are the SAME issues when installing the runtime. So, just like multiple versions of access can be a problem on the same computer, the same applies to the runtime.

I explain what the runtime is and answer a good number of your questions here:

http://www.members.shaw.ca/AlbertKallal/RunTime/Index.html